# Using Trezor, My list of tokens is gone and my alt coins do not appear in myetherwallet.

Tags: myetherwallet, erc-20, trezor

Hi Guys I hope someone can help me. Using Trezor and myetherwallet for sending and receiving ETH and other ERC20 tokens. Successfully using for months. I opened my "View wallet info" today and the entire list of tokens are gone. Token balances are gone, drop down on "amount to send" only shows ETH. (NOte all my ETH is still there but I am unable to see, send or figure out what happened to all of my ERC20 tokens. I have a bunch of different tokens I have been trading. Any advice please?

Comment: This link from your reply doesn't work: 'You can learn how to check the balance of your account here.' Can you fix it please

Answer (score 1):

We have temporarily disabled viewing all tokens by default due to the servers being overloaded because people were using MEW to check token balances and somehow managed to check 4M balances in like15 minutes which is nutty and expensive.

If you need to check other token balances: you can add custom token or wait a few hours until we bring them back.

If you were having issues loading all balances: this should be resolved, or try a differnt network (etherscan / infura) via the dropdown in top-right corner

- [The most up to date instructions on how to add a custom token can be found here.](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/send/adding-new-token-and-sending-custom-tokens.html)
- [The list of token addresses / decimals / symbols is here.](https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/ethereum-lists/blob/master/tokens-eth.json) They are in alpha-order.
- [You can learn how to check the balance of your account here.](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/getting-started/checking-balance-of-my-account.html)

I hope this helps. Please let me know if anything wasn't clear or you need any more assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: Why couldn't you just spin up more servers?

Comment: Tayvano, heart attack averted... Faith in humanity AND Trezor/Myetherwallet restored! Thank you thank you did I mention thank you? :)

Comment: @0xcaff (1) we already have 10 (2) we spend over 5k/month (3) we like to eat dinner (4) we didn't expect people to use a wallet instead of a blockchain explorer to check balances, esp considering you couldnt participate in 0x via MEW (5) keeping them online would have likely cost 600-700 bucks